# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints after updating height

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a cell with two image views:
[image: Cell]

Constraints for the small image view:
[image: Small]

Constraints for the big one:
[image: Big]

Constraints for the button:
[image: Button]

The big image view has "Scale to Fill" content mode.

I don't know size of image before I load it with SDWebImage, so I've created constant height constraint and its outlet in code.

When the image is loaded, I'm changing height constraint's constant to keep image's aspect:

```
imageIv.sd_setImage(with: feedAd.getImageUrl(), completed: { (image: UIImage?, error: Error?, cacheType: SDImageCacheType!, imageURL: URL?) in
                if image != nil {
                    let ratio = image!.size.height / image!.size.width
                    self.imageHeightConstraint.constant = self.imageIv.frame.width * ratio
                    self.updateConstraints()
                } else {
                    print("Image == nil!")
                }

                if self.imageViewLoadedCallback != nil {
                    self.imageViewLoadedCallback!()
                }
            })
```

And then I see the following:

```
2017-01-13 00:21:10.387862 DotaTo[1541:503878] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17008df70 UIImageView:0x102d39000.height == 48>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174098bf0 UIImageView:0x102e59e40.height == 228.667>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17409bc10 UIImageView:0x102d39000.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x102d4bae0.top + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174098010 UIImageView:0x102e59e40.top == UIImageView:0x102d39000.bottom + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17409aae0 UIButton:0x102e6c600.top == UIImageView:0x102e59e40.bottom + 16>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17409aa40 UITableViewCellContentView:0x102d4bae0.bottom == UIButton:0x102e6c600.bottom + 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x17009be40 UITableViewCellContentView:0x102d4bae0.height == 293>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x174098bf0 UIImageView:0x102e59e40.height == 228.667>
```

The cell height is not updated, so view is height-cutted. But when I scroll the table view down unless this cell becomes out of screen and then scroll back to it, it resizes correctly.

So, I have two questions:

1. How to resolve this error?
2. How to make cell to adjust it's height
   correctly?

Comment: Which UIImageView are you trying to update? The error says it's the small one.

Comment: @dfd, no, imageHeightConstraint is height constraint of the big one.

Comment: @dfd there are different pointers in dump: 0x102d39000 and 0x102e59e40. Also, see the screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/IpErFG4.png

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to adjust a table cells content height, which is where the constraint issue is. Looking at the cell layout though, would it be possible to replace the table view with a stack view?